# Stop/hide javascript running depending on current day and time? (jquery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project (live chat) which uses some javascript code to place a chat button onto a web page. What I'd like to do, depending specifically on which day of the week it is and what time it is - is either display or hide this javascript code, ergo, the button only appears when the live chat is "open".

I have looked into jquery which seems very capable of this, however, I have not used it before and I'm having trouble working out the code.

I found a project (https://jsfiddle.net/16mnrL3b/) which seems to do the basics of what I need, but I have no idea how to input values per day. I'd need each day to have different opening hours, e.g. Monday - 9 am to 5 pm, Tuesday - 10 am - 4 pm etc...

```
//gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 15 ){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {  
     $(".closed").show();
    $(".open").hide();
}
```

--

```
<div class = "open">Shop is open</div>
<div class = "closed">Shop is closed</div>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does the above code currently work?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay
Note: maybe you want to update it's status one time in several minutes. So see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 2):

Look more into [Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

```
// 0 Sunday
// 1 Monday
// 2 Tuesday
// ...
// 6 Saturday

var d = new Date();
var openHours = 0;
var closedHours = 0;

switch(d.getDay()) {
    case 0:
        openHours = 7;
        closeHours = 17;
        break;
    case 1:
        openHours = 8;
        closeHours = 18;
        break;
    case 2:
        openHours = 7;
        closeHours = 17;
        break;
    case 3:
        openHours = 8;
        closeHours = 18;
    case 4:
        openHours = 7;
        closeHours = 17;
        break;
    case 5:
        openHours = 7;
        closeHours = 17;
        break;
    case 6:
        openHours = 9;
        closeHours = 15;
        break;
}


if(d.getHours() >= openHours && d.getHours() <= closeHours) {
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}else {
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".closed").show();
}
```

This will set the hours depending on the day and display them accordingly

Comment: Is it possible to set end times for the next day (after midnight)? Example working hours: Monday 22:00 - 5:30, Tuesday 22:00- 4:30.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getDay function to return the day of the week 0-6

```
if(d.getDay() < 5){ //weekday hours
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 15 ){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
  }//and so on
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this seems to be what I need! Any idea how I'd do this for each day? Would I simply replicate the code 7 times for each day of the week?

Comment: I'd recommend a switch case
`switch(d.getDay()) {
    case 0://monday
        {code block}
        break;
    case 1: //tues
        {code block}
        break;
...
    default:
        code block
} `

Answer (score 0):

date and time calculation can be really confusing and once we add code we always keep adding the logic on top of the previously written code.

So it's important that we make it clear and readable.

Here is what I will do

1- create weekday array so we don't have to keep track of zero index weekday from d.getHours() and always figure out what does 0,3,5 means....

2- create readable object literal with properties for each day and assign open and close time.

```
var d = new Date();

var weekDays =
 ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'];

var weeklyTimeTable = {
    monday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    tuesday: { open: 8, close: 10 },
    wednesday: { open: 9, close: 10 },
    thursday: { open: 10, close: 10 },
    friday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    saturday: { open: 8, close: 10 },
    sunady: { open: 9, close: 10 }
```

}

```
function showOpenClose() {
    $('.open').hide();
    $('.closed').hide();

    if (d.getHours() >= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].open && 
        d.getHours() <= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].close) {
        $('.open').show();
    } else {
        $'.closed').show();
    }
}
```