# jquery to hide/show javascript during opening times not working (code issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is probably something really simple, so please accept my apologies. I made a post yesterday [Stop/hide javascript running depending on current day and time? (jquery?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768446/stop-hide-javascript-running-depending-on-current-day-and-time-jquery) and was provided with some code to achieve what I need. I have put this code together (below) but I can't seem to get this working and wonder if you guys can please help again...

The compiled code is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var d = new Date();

var weekDays =
 ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'];

var weeklyTimeTable = {
    monday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    tuesday: { open: 8, close: 10 },
    wednesday: { open: 9, close: 10 },
    thursday: { open: 10, close: 10 },
    friday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    saturday: { open: 8, close: 10 },
    sunady: { open: 9, close: 10 }
}
function showOpenClose() {
    $('.open').hide();
    $('.closed').hide();

    if (d.getHours() >= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].open && 
        d.getHours() <= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].closed) {
        $('.open').show();
    } else {
        $'.closed').show();
    }
}
</script> 
</head>

   <body>
<div class = "open">Open Test</div>
<div class = "closed">Closed Test</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

What should happen, depending on the times under the "weeklyTimeTable" is that either "Open Test" or "Closed Test" should display when the page is loaded. At the moment, both "Open Test" and "Closed Test" are showing so the code doesn't seem to work.

Debugging the code in Chrome developer tools shows an 'unexpected string' for `$'.closed').show();`

As I mentioned in my other post, this is the first time I've used jquery so I'm not sure how to fix this.

The overall aim of the project is to place some javascript code between the div tags to display a live chat button only during opening times.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Edit:

I have amended

```
$'.closed').show();
```

To

```
$'(.closed').show();
```

However the code is still not working (both div elements are shown) instead of just one. Chrome also still shows an 'unexpected string' for this line.

Comment: Missing parenthesis `$'.closed')` should be `$('.closed')`

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis chrome shows that correctly! ;)

Comment: This should be closed - It is a typo error

Comment: I have amended $'.closed').show(); to $'(.closed').show(); however the code still won't run and displays both div elements instead of either open or closed.

Comment: how is the "showOpenClose()" function actually triggered? Nothing seems to cause the function to run. Also, if the user leaves the page open for a long time, the status might no longer be valid. You might want to consider re-checking the status at regular intervals and updating (you can use the setInterval function for this to run your code as often as you like).

Comment: @adyson do you have any suggestions for how to trigger this? On page load would be fine but I am unsure how to do this

Comment: @dvnnvd as per Osama's answer would be the right way to trigger it - that will run it at page load. If you want it to run at set intervals additionally, then you can google how to use the setInterval feature to trigger a function to run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to call the **showOpenClose()** function.

Add the below code snippet inside your script tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showOpenClose();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By mistake you use closed instead of close in if statement so it will not work as you expected I solve it and here is the full right code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var d = new Date();

var weekDays =
 ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'];

var weeklyTimeTable = {
    monday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    tuesday: { open: 8, close: 20 },
    wednesday: { open: 9, close: 10 },
    thursday: { open: 10, close: 10 },
    friday: { open: 7, close: 10 },
    saturday: { open: 8, close: 10 },
    sunady: { open: 9, close: 10 }
}
function showOpenClose() {
    $('.open').hide();
    $('.closed').hide();
    if (d.getHours() >= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].open && 
        d.getHours() <= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay()-1]].close) {
        $('.open').show();
    } else {
        $('.closed').show();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    showOpenClose();
});
</script> 
</head>

   <body>
<div class = "open">Open Test</div>
<div class = "closed">Closed Test</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using this code. Unfortunately despite times being set, I always see "Closed Test". I don't seem to be able to get the "Open Test" div to display. Any suggestions?

Comment: thank you so much for this! you are amazing. I don't suppose you know if it's possible to set a specific timezone? for example if a user in another time zone loaded the code, it may still show as open, despite actually being closed. Is there a way to account for time difference that you are aware of?

Comment: check this may be it will help you

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. 
Call showOpenClose() function.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();

    var weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];

    var weeklyTimeTable = {
      monday: {
        open: 7,
        close: 10
      },
      tuesday: {
        open: 8,
        close: 10
      },
      wednesday: {
        open: 9,
        close: 10
      },
      thursday: {
        open: 10,
        close: 10
      },
      friday: {
        open: 7,
        close: 10
      },
      saturday: {
        open: 8,
        close: 10
      },
      sunady: {
        open: 9,
        close: 10
      }
    }

    function showOpenClose() {
      $('.open').hide();
      $('.closed').hide();
      if (d.getHours() >= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay() - 1]].open &&
        d.getHours() <= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay() - 1]].close) {
        $('.open').show();

      } else {
        $('.closed').show();
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      showOpenClose();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="open">Open Test</div>
  <div class="closed">Closed Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This seems to be the solution (no errors!), however, it seems like no matter what time is set, I always see "closed test". Any idea what maybe the problem here?

Comment: there is 1 small typo mistake in this line
**d.getHours() <= weeklyTimeTable[weekDays[d.getDay() - 1]].closed) {**
instead of **closed** it has to be **close**